# Pythonw stuck on python2.7 on MacOS X 10.15.7 in conda environment

Tags: python, macos, pythonw

How can I force **pythonw** to use python3 instead of python2? Here are the outputs from my zsh terminal (MacOS X 10.15.7):

```
python --version
>> Python 3.8.5

python3 --version
>> Python 3.8.10
```

However when it comes to pythonw, I get such an output:

```
pythonw --version
>> Python 2.7.16
```

How can I make the pythonw to execute using python3?

Additional info - I am trying to install DeepLabCut software package with [these instructions](https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/blob/master/docs/installation.md#technical-considerations), and everything works fine until I try to execute the command `pythonw -m deeplabcut` as suggested [here](https://github.com/DeepLabCut/DeepLabCut/blob/master/docs/standardDeepLabCut_UserGuide.md) and I receive an error that is most likely linked to the Python version (DLC requires Python>3.7), thus my question. Please note that I work in a conda (conda version 4.10.3) environment.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone struggles with this as well - run the following command:

```
conda install python.app
```

This will update the pythonw and make everything work.